# Animation text not showing properly in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to add animated text(something like"Developed by .....") to Home page of my App.
But i couldn't show it completely.every time its length equals to shows only the width of the device. How can I solve this issue.My coding are as follows.

In my Home Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

Animation animation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView txtAnimation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAnimation);
    animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(HomeActivity.this,R.anim.move);

    String string="Developed by ................";

    // set animation listener
    animation.setAnimationListener(this);
    txtAnimation.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

My move.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"

    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:duration="8000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
    <!--android:toXDelta="0%p"-->
</set>
```

I tried by using setMaxWidth,setEmsbut not worked.